# Western Digital Workbook World Edition

Tags: windows-7

I have a new laptop with windows 7 and i have tried installing the driver for my workbook so i can get to my back up files.  I am getting a message telling me the driver is incompatible with windows 7 and therefore i need some suggestions as to what to do next.  Thanks J

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the updated driver from Western Digital? It appears that there is a new version on the web site that supports win 7.

Comment: Hi there - thanks Josh for your clarification.  When WD Support download is back up and running I will endeavour to download appropriate software.

Answer (score 0):

When I bought a MyBook World Edition, I didn't bother with the included CD. Just downloaded the latest software from the WD site. Works fine on my two Win7 machines.

Comment: thanks Grant- Both answers have cleared it up for me.  I thought so - just needed a bit of guidance...mind you I haven't done it yet!!